# Sorting By Multiple Conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, operators, comparison-operators, spacecraft-operator

I have a collection of Post objects and I want to be able to sort them based on these conditions:

- First, by category (news, events, labs, portfolio, etc.)
- Then by date, if date, or by position, if a specific index was set for it

Some posts will have dates (news and events), others will have explicit positions (labs, and portfolio).

I want to be able to call `posts.sort!`, so I've overridden `<=>`, but am looking for the most effective way of sorting by these conditions.  Below is a pseudo method:

```
def <=>(other)
  # first, everything is sorted into 
  # smaller chunks by category
  self.category <=> other.category

  # then, per category, by date or position
  if self.date and other.date
    self.date <=> other.date
  else
    self.position <=> other.position
  end
end
```

It seems like I'd have to actually sort two separate times, rather than cramming everything into that one method.  Something like `sort_by_category`, then `sort!`.  What is the most ruby way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should always sort by the same criteria to insure a meaningful order. If comparing two `nil` dates, it is fine that the `position` will judge of the order, but if comparing one `nil` date with a set date, you have to decide which goes first, irrespective of the position (for example by mapping `nil` to a day way in the past).

Otherwise imagine the following:

```
a.date = nil                   ; a.position = 1
b.date = Time.now - 1.day      ; b.position = 2
c.date = Time.now              ; c.position = 0
```

By your original criteria, you would have:  a < b < c < a. So, which one is the smallest??

You also want to do the sort at once. For your `<=>` implementation, use `#nonzero?`:

```
def <=>(other)
  return nil unless other.is_a?(Post)
  (self.category <=> other.category).nonzero? ||
  ((self.date || AGES_AGO) <=> (other.date || AGES_AGO)).nonzero? ||
  (self.position <=> other.position).nonzero? ||
  0
end
```

If you use your comparison criteria just once, or if that criteria is not universal and thus don't want to define `<=>`, you could use `sort` with a block:

```
post_ary.sort{|a, b| (a.category <=> ...).non_zero? || ... }
```

Better still, there is `sort_by` and `sort_by!` which you can use to build an array for what to compare in which priority:

```
post_ary.sort_by{|a| [a.category, a.date || AGES_AGO, a.position] }
```

Besides being shorter, using `sort_by` has the advantage that you can only obtain a well ordered criteria.

Notes:

- `sort_by!` was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2. You can [`require 'backports/1.9.2/array/sort_by'`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) to use it with older Rubies.
- I'm assuming that `Post` is not a subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base` (in which case you'd want the sort to be done by the db server).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `Numeric#nonzero?`. Isn't a bit odd for a `?`-method to return non-boolean values?

Comment: @Mladen: It is, but quite useful. Another example where you could expect a `true/false`: `String < Fixnum` returns `nil`, not `false`.

Comment: This is a bit misleading:
`post_ary.sort_by {|a, b| (a.category <=> ...) }`
sort_by doesn't take a block with two arguments. Instead for more complex sorting problems you should return an array.. I.e.:
`post_ary.sort_by {|a| [a.category, a.date, a.position] }`

Comment: @TimoLehto: Absolutely, thanks for pointing out my mistake. Edited accordingly.

Comment: why id you have : .nonzero? || 0 is there special conditions when you need this || 0

Comment: @tolbard No reason, just to show the pattern. The last `nonzero?` and the last `||` can be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could do the sort in one fell swoop in an array, the only gotcha is handling the case where one of the attributes is nil, although that could still be handled if you knew the data set by selecting the appropriate nil guard.  Also it's not clear from your psuedo code if the date and position comparisons are listed in a priority order or an one or the other (i.e. use date if exists for both else use position).  First solution assumes use, category, followed by date, followed by position

```
def <=>(other)
    [self.category, self.date, self.position] <=> [other.category, other.date, other.position]
end
```

Second assumes it's date or position

```
def <=>(other)
    if self.date && other.date
        [self.category, self.date] <=> [other.category, other.date]
    else
        [self.category, self.position] <=> [other.category, other.position]
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah, had forgotten about the `nil` of dates. This sort order is not well ordered (see my updated answer).

Comment: For my learning, what do you mean by it not being well ordered?

Comment: For a well-founded order, the following always holds: `a < b && b < c` implies `a < c`. See my answer for an example where it isn't the case with this criteria.

Comment: But then you could get that with the following tweak to the first case:
    [self.category, self.date || AGES_AGO, self.position] <=> [other.category, other.date || AGES_AGO, other.position]
to use your nomeclature, right, not as elegant but same result without your extra checks

Comment: Yes, using an array this way is fine. It will be slower though, especially if some fields need to be calculated (say `#position` is a method making some calculations), but will yield the same result.